# 2 app delegates, swift and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, appdelegate

So, I have an app mixed with objective-c and swift, (originally objective-c) And I need to figure out how to have 2 app delegates (one for swift, and the other for objective-c). I've done some research, but found nothing. Please help!

**EDIT:**

So, I succesfully switched, but now in my delegate, i have this code:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

But, splitViewController isn't the first vc, so how would I go around fixing it? (I don't know swift very well)

Comment: You can't. Apps can only have one delegate and you have to chose if you want to do it in Swift or Objective C.

Comment: If I did it in swift, would it mess up my other code? And how would I go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

You only need one delegate, do it in Swift. If you create a new app Xcode will use some default code, which as of 8.3.1 is the following:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

To answer the comment: it doesn't mess up your code. Remove previous Objective C delegate if needed.

Comment: So delete the old app delegate, and put a new one?

Comment: You can't have both... so if you want to use this one, you have to remove the other

Comment: @user7847400 why did you want to change that in the first place?

Comment: Im going to edit my question, I fixed my errors; but now I have a question about setting VC's

Comment: Don't change the context of a question! Ask a new one instead. Reason: The previous answers are useless now and doesn't help others any more.